# MPI executable and sharing stdin

Tags: c++, mpi

I am coding my first programs using `MPI`. I was used to `openMP` but this seems much harder..!

I am facing a problem now with data passed as `stdin`. I am running my program using the following:

```
cat DATAfile | mpirun -n 8 ./a.out
```

and what I am seeing is that only the `rank 0` thread has a non empty `stdin`. Is it possible to share it from the beginning? As it is made of `sting` objects, it would be cumbersome to pass it inside with `MPI` directives.

edit: found what I wanted in the documentation:
http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.3/man1/mpirun.1.php

adding `-stdin all` does the job.

```
cat DATAfile | mpirun -n 8 -stdin all ./a.out
```

Sorry for the bother...

Comment: Don't put the answer into the question. There is no problem [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). After a certain time, you can even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the answer was in the documentation:
http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.3/man1/mpirun.1.php

```
cat DATAfile | mpirun -n 8 -stdin all ./a.out
```

Comment: You are right, I moved the extra interrogating bit to a new question thread.